# Stuff with xml is taking so much time in my query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a view from the view need to fetch some result set for that purpose I have wrote following query.

So here the problem is `stuff` `with xml` is taking so much time any suggestions please.

```
;WITH CTE_transaction_type1  AS
(
    SELECT  case_summary_id,Primary_Payer, Physician,Generate_Bill,
    CASE 
            WHEN Current_Payer IS NULL
                THEN CASE 
                        WHEN Resposible_Patient_Name IS NULL
                            AND PG_Patient_Name IS NULL
                            THEN 'PG:' + Patient_Last_Name + ',' + Patient_First_Name
                        WHEN Resposible_Patient_Name IS NULL
                            AND NULLIF(PG_Patient_Name,' ') IS NOT NULL
                            THEN 'SG:' + Patient_Last_Name + ',' + Patient_First_Name
                        ELSE Resposible_Patient_Name
                        END
            ELSE 
                    CASE 
                    WHEN Current_Payer_Name IS NULL
                        THEN ''
                    ELSE Insurance_Type + Current_Payer_Name + IIF(Plan_Name IS NULL, '', ',' + Plan_Name)
                    END
     END AS Responsible_Party_List
    FROM [charts].[vw_billing_analysis] 
    WHERE  sort_order = 0 AND transaction_type_id = 1
)


SELECT ba.Case_Summary_ID
    ,ba.date_of_surgery
    ,ba.Organization_ID
    ,ba.Organization_Name
    ,ba.Patient_Name
    ,ba.Patient_First_Name
    ,ba.Patient_Last_Name
    ,ba.MRN
    ,ba.Physician_ID
    ,ba.Physician
    ,ba.[PROCEDURE]
    ,ba.Current_Payer
    ,ba.Current_Payer_Name
    ,ba.Primary_Payer
    ,ba.Primary_Payer_ID
    ,ba.Insurance_Plan_ID
    ,ba.Insurance_Plan_Type
    ,ba.Plan_Name
    ,ba.Speciality_ID
    ,ba.Speciality_Name
    ,ba.Transaction_Responsible_Party_ID
    ,ba.Charge_ID
    ,ba.Charge_Procedure_ID
    ,ba.Patient_Insurance_ID
    ,ba.Insurance_Type
    ,ba.Resposible_Patient_Name
    ,ba.Received_From
    ,ba.Guarantor_Master_ID
    ,ba.PG_Patient_Name
    ,ba.Batch_Description
    ,ba.Period_Name
    ,ba.Unassigned_payment
    ,ba.Charge
    ,ba.Charge_Corr
    ,ba.Debit
    ,ba.Payments
    ,ba.WriteOff
    ,ba.Balance
    ,ba.Corrected_TF
    ,ba.Period_ID
    ,ba.Batch_ID
    ,ba.transaction_type_id
    ,STUFF((
            SELECT '; ' + [Procedure]
            FROM [charts].[vw_billing_analysis] vba
            WHERE vba.case_summary_id = ba.case_summary_id
                AND vba.transaction_type_id = 1
            ORDER BY ba.sort_order
            FOR XML PATH('')
                ,TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') AS Procedure_List
    ,trty1.Primary_Payer AS Primary_Payer_List
    ,trty1.Responsible_Party_List
    ,trty1.Physician AS Physician_List
    ,ba.Allowed_Amount
    ,IIF(ba.insurance_contract_id IS NULL
        OR ba.Insurance_Plan_Type = 'Self-Pay', NULL, iif(ba.procedure_type IS NOT NULL, round(ba.[allowed_amount] - (ba.[allowed_amount] * ba.procedure_discount / 100.0), 3), ba.[procedure_amount])) AS [Expected_Amount]
    ,ba.Procedure_Amount
    ,ba.Generate_Bill
    ,trty1.Generate_Bill AS Generate_Bill_Case
    ,ba.Actual_Payment
    ,ba.First_Bill_Date
FROM [charts].[vw_billing_analysis] ba
left join cte_transaction_type1 trty1
ON ba.Case_Summary_ID=trty1.Case_Summary_ID
WHERE ba.Organization_ID =52

    AND
    (
        (
            (
                (
                    ba.Period_Id = ('999999999')
                    OR '999999999' = '999999999'
                    )
                AND 0 = 1
                )
            AND (
                (
                    ba.Batch_Id IN ('999999999')
                    OR '999999999' = '999999999'
                    )
                AND 0 = 1
                )
            )
        OR (
            0 = 0
            AND ba.date_of_surgery >= '2018-02-01'
            AND ba.date_of_surgery <= '2021-03-03'
            )
        )
    AND (
        CASE 
            WHEN ba.Insurance_Plan_Type IS NULL
                AND ba.Insurance_Plan_ID IS NULL
                AND ba.Current_Payer IS NULL
                THEN '-1'
            ELSE ba.Insurance_Plan_Type_Id
            END IN ('999999999')
        OR '999999999' = '999999999'
        )
    AND (
        ba.Current_Payer IN ('999999999')
        OR '999999999' = '999999999'
        )
    AND (
        ba.Speciality_ID IN ('999999999')
        OR '999999999' = '999999999'
        )
    AND (
        ba.Physician_ID IN ('999999999')
        OR '999999999' = '999999999'
        )
    AND (
        isnull(ba.Primary_Payer_ID, - 1) IN ('999999999')
        OR '999999999' = '999999999'
        )
    AND (
        ba.appointment_type_id IN ('999999999')
        OR '999999999' = '999999999'
        )
    AND (
        SELECT SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN vba.transaction_type_id = 1
                        THEN balance
                    WHEN vba.transaction_type_id = 3
                        THEN - balance
                    END)
        FROM [charts].[vw_billing_analysis] vba
        WHERE vba.case_summary_id = ba.case_summary_id
        ) >= 0
ORDER BY ba.Date_Of_Surgery DESC
    ,ba.MRN DESC
    ,ba.Patient_Name ASC
    ,ba.upd_tr_sort ASC
    ,ba.Sort_Order ASC
```

Comment: *"I have a view from the view"* That could be your *real* problem. Using a `VIEW` which references a `VIEW`, can end up with poor query plans. SQL isn't a programming language; minimisation of code like that doesn't work well.

Comment: This is a pretty massive query.  Best place to start is just by looking at all bottlenecks and trying to optimize them via indices or maybe remove them by refactoring.

Comment: All those `OR`s in the `WHERE` are unlikely to help as well, and that `CASE` isn't SARGable. I also don't understand why you have clauses like `AND 0 = 1` in your `WHERE`. That will never be true.

Comment: @Larnu i want to avoid stuff any alternative because it is eating execution time

Comment: How do you "know" `STUFF` is the problem? All `STUFF` does is remove and inject characters from a string. It is not an expensive function.

Comment: @Larnu  if i remove that stuff statment and run the query it is returning results quickly but if i use comma seperated (stuff) means it is taking time

Comment: `STUFF` doesn't create delimited results, it's `FOR XML PATH` that does that.

Comment: And if the `FOR XML QUERY` is slow, I would pull that query out, run it separately, get the execution plan and performance tune that.

Comment: You have **two** self join on the view, you probably want a window aggregate instead. And all those `WHERE` predicates are going to be elided

Comment: Change `).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')` to `).value('(./text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'')`. That can help avoid a costly nested loop operator in the plan to parse the XML, which is costly with many rows. That may help somewhat but nested views are a recipe for poor performance.

Comment: @DanGuzman still same time it is taking

Comment: @Larnu that is the reason iam keeping out of CTE and doing XML operation

Comment: I don't understand your comment, doing what? So you *have* performance tuned the `FOR XML PATH` query? Can you therefore post the execution plan for it? If that query is performant, then I doubt it's the problem, and it's the rest of the query combined with the `FOR XML PATH`. Again, there's a reason several of us have advised you against the nested Views; I suggest looking there.

Comment: how  to post my execution plan

Comment: @Chanukya, execute your query from SSMS with the include actual execution plan option (under query menu bar). Then upload the plan XML to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question.